# Why am I getting a column not found error when trying to return a collection model based on user ID?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I'm trying to return all Threads that a given User has participated in.

The endpoint accepts a userId and supposed to return a collection of thread models.

However, I keep getting this error when executing the controller action.  It's looking for a `message_id` column but I don't have that defined on the `thread` table or on any table, for that matter - making this a weird error.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'thread.message_id' in 'where 
clause' (SQL: select * from `thread` where `thread`.`message_id` = 2 and 
`thread`.`message_id` is not null)"
```

I believe there might be something off with how I'm linking the tables but I'm not entirely sure. I'd assume the `message` table's column `thread_id` should reference the `id` column on the `thread` table which's what I thought I was doing in the `message` migration below.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Here's users migration:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id('id');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('full_name');
        $table->string('password');
});
```

Here's thread migration:

```
Schema::create('thread', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
});
```

Here's message migration:

```
Schema::create('message', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('thread_id');
        $table->string('body');
        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('thread_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('thread')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

controller action:

```
public function getUserThreads($userId) {
    $userParticipatedThreads = Message::findOrFail($userId);
    return $userParticipatedThreads->thread;
}
```

message model:

```
public function thread() {
    return $this->hasMany(Thread::class);
}
```

endpoint:

```
[GET] http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/getUserThreads/2

Route::get('getUserThreads/{userId}', [ThreadController::class, 'getUserThreads']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question;

> Why am I getting a column not found error when trying to return a
> collection model based on user ID?

Because your `thread` table doesn't have a `message_id` field defined on it.

```
Schema::create('thread', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
});
```

A `Message` belongs to a `Thread` but you seem to have that relationship inverted.

On your `Thread` model, define a relationship to the `Message` model:

```
public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class);
}
```

Then you can query for the existance of some message by user:

```
$messages = Thread::whereHas('messages', function ($query) use ($userId) {
    $query->where('user_id', $userId);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `thread` relationship on your Message class is looking for the `message_id`, since that's the default way the hasMany relationship works. You'll need to override the column that it's basing the relationship off of.

```
public function thread() {
    return $this->hasMany(Thread::class, 'id', 'thread_id');
}
```

However, since it looks like the message belongs to one single thread (each message has a thread_id), then you actually want `belongsTo` instead

```
public function thread() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Thread::class);
}
```